# Swing: how to add two JScrollPanes with TableLayout?

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, layout-manager, tablelayout

For my Java program I am actually using the simple library `TableLayout` as layout for my main `JPanel` body so that I can add any widget just by specifying its row and column index, for example"

```
body.add(new JLabel(
            "Search by date"),
            "1,8");
```

Now I would need to add two `JScrollPane` (one horizontal and one vertical) but they should include all the body and not just a single cell of the layout. Shall I add another `JPanel`? How can I do it?

Comment: `TableLayout` Where did you get that?

Comment: one horizontal and one vertical - what do you want to do with empty space, because description (one horizontal and one vertical) talking about 3rd. and empty area

Comment: Someone here in stackoverflow advised me to use it. Isn't it good?

Comment: *"Someone here in stackoverflow advised me to use it."*  (Looks around) Stack Overflow is a big place.  Care to narrow it down with a link?

Comment: I mean that I would need one scroll to scroll the page horizontally and one to scroll the page up and down. But maybe just the horizontal one could be enough

Comment: I got TableLayout from here http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/tablelayout-141489.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Now I would need to add two `JScrollPane` (one horizontal and one
>   vertical) but they should include all the body and not just a single
>   cell of the layout. Shall I add another `JPanel`?*

IMO, yes you should. [Nesting Layouts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/1795530) is a common approach that could be applied in this way:

- Create a new `JScrollPane` and set your panel as its viewport view.
- Give the scroll pane a reasonable preferred size to enable the scroll bars if your panel's size exceeds this preferred size.
- Have a wrapper panel with `BorderLayout` and add the scroll pane to its CENTER location.

In a nutshell:

```
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(yourPanel);
scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 300));

JPanel wrapperPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
wrapperPanel.add(scrollPane);
```

---

See also:

- [How to Use Scroll Panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html)

Comment: I still need your help if you can. I have followed all your instructions and everything was fine. Yesterday I tried to add new items into the body (JButtons, JLabels...) and even if I had added the JScrollPane they are not shown when I scroll down the main page. In other words, I divided the main JPanel into 11 rows and 7 columns using tablelayout.jar by Oracle. If I add another row or two they are not shown and I do not know why. You can read the following link for further information. Can you help me?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27446966/java-gui-tablelayout-how-to-add-more-many-widgets-in-a-jframe-with-a-scroll-bar